# ngIF keeps looping forever in Ionic4

Tags: angular, loops, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I am developing a chat application with Chat Group functionality. I have created "Create New Group" and "Edit Existing Group" pages. In my "Edit Group" page, I am loading all the users list and checking members if they are already present in the group in order to provide the functionality to add or remove existing member as well as new member. My code is like this:

**edit-group.page.html**

```
//Here I have around 150 friends/total users
<ion-item *ngFor="let friend of friends | friendFilter: searchFriend">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img src="{{ friend.photoURL }}" onError="this.src='./assets/img/default-dp.png'"/>
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
        <h2>{{ friend.fullName }}</h2>
        <p class="emailCustom">{{ friend.email }}</p>
    </ion-label>

//****This is where I am facing problem. 
//**** This buttons are add or remove members. Notice here my *ngIF statement! 

    <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" color = "light" (click)="addToGroup(friend); $event.stopPropagation()" *ngIf="!inGroup(friend) && checkadmin()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" color = "light" (click)="removeFromGroup(friend); $event.stopPropagation()" *ngIf="inGroup(friend) && checkadmin()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

Notice the `*ngIf` state in the ion-button.

This `*ngIf` check if the friend is already a member of the group through `inGroup()` function and it also checks where the friend is an admin using `checkadmin()` function.

My functions are as below:

**edit-group.page.ts**

```
inGroup(friend) {
    //Currently this.groupMembers.lenth is 3 but this function is called 150 times as I have 150 users
    for (var i = 0; i < this.groupMembers.length; i++) {  
      console.log("Kartik In Group Count: " + i);
      if (this.groupMembers[i].$key == friend.$key) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  checkadmin() {
    if (this.group.admin == this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

So what is happenening is, I have total of 150 users which loops through the `*ngFor="let friend of friends"` in my ion-item in html. and for each friend, `inGroup(friend)` and `checkadmin()` functions are checked.

Now, my app runs into loop forever as soon as the page loads. The `inGroup()` and `checkAdmin()` function are keeps on looping through `*ngIf`. Any idea what am I doing wrong here????

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not have any console errors in browser and you have the data available, I can't really say what is wrong.

But I would use the `*ngIf else` to render the HTML and update my code as below:

```
 <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" color = "light" (click)="removeFromGroup(friend); $event.stopPropagation()" *ngIf="inGroup(friend) && checkadmin(); else notInGroup">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>

<ng-template #notInGroup
<ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" color = "light" (click)="addToGroup(friend); $event.stopPropagation()">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
</ng-template>
```

Also update your `inGroup(friend)` to be something like this using lodash function or [java script `some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
inGroup(friend) {
    return _.some(this.groupMembers, (member) => member.$key === friend.$key);
}
```

And checkadmin can be a boolean set in your OnInit and used in `*ngIf`:

```
boolean isAdmin  = (this.group.admin === this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)
```

Comment: It still keeps on lopping inside inGroup() function :(

Comment: do you see any errors? Can you create a stackblitz example with sample data for us to check?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid using methods in `*ngIf` as variable will not have any performance issue since it is directly checked against a variable, while the method will use change detection and it will be fired many times.

So try to create some variable after getting data from your response, e.g. `isAdmin`:

```
<ion-button fill="clear" slot="end" color = "light" 
    (click)="removeFromGroup(friend); $event.stopPropagation()" 
    *ngIf="friend?.isAdmin">
    <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```